# MVC Project users table location

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am making a simple MVC Cookbook web application to store recipes I make and give them a rating. It's more of a learning project then anything else. I used microsoft's Contoso University code first example located

[Here](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

My project is simpler, they have 3 entity classes (student, enrollment, course) where as I only have one (recipe)

As I said before, this was a code first approach, so I designed my recipe class

Recipe.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Recipes.Models
{
    public class Recipe
    {
        public int RecipeID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
        public int Calories { get; set; }
        public int Protein { get; set; }
        public int Carbs { get; set; }
        public int Fat { get; set; }
        public bool Spicy{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

And created a DAL (data access layer) folder that contains my database context and initiator with some test data.

RecipeContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Recipes.Models;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace Recipes.DAL
{
    public class RecipeContext : DbContext
    {
        public RecipeContext() : base("RecipeContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }


}
```

RecipeInitializor.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Recipes.Models;

namespace Recipes.DAL
{
    public class RecipeInitializor : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<RecipeContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(RecipeContext context)
        {
            var Recipes = new List<Recipe>
            {
                new Recipe {RecipeID = 111, Name = "Chicken Fajitas", Calories = 500, Carbs = 35, Fat = 10, Protein = 35, EntryDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-08-01"), Spicy = true},
                new Recipe {RecipeID = 112, Name = "Dijon Chicken", Calories= 415, Carbs = 10, Fat = 5, Protein = 30, EntryDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-09-01"), Spicy = false},
                new Recipe {RecipeID = 113, Name = "Turkey Chili", Calories = 475, Carbs = 25, Fat = 5, Protein = 40, EntryDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-09-05"), Spicy = true },
                new Recipe {RecipeID = 114, Name = "Beef Stew", Calories= 515, Carbs = 28, Fat = 15, Protein = 30, EntryDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-07-06"), Spicy = false }
            };

            Recipes.ForEach(s => context.Recipes.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            //base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
    //class RecipeInitializor
    //{
    //}
}
```

When I ran this project, it created a table for me, called recipes. 
[image: SQL Server explorer]

My question is, where are the users stored? When creating the project, I decided to keep individual accounts for the log in system. I've created one user with a username and password and I can log into the site using this so I know it has to be stored somewhere. When I google the issue, people keep saying its located in the App_Data folder but there is nothing inside mine.

[image: App_Data]

So where is the database for the users? And how can I have it placed in the same location as my Recipes database?

EDIT Requested updates

IdentityModel.cs

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace Recipes.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RecipeContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Recipes1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="Recipes.DAL.RecipeContext, Recipes">
        <databaseInitializer type="Recipes.DAL.RecipeInitializor, Recipes"></databaseInitializer>
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

ADDITIONAL EDIT

I clicked 'show all files' in the solution explorer but still don't see anything. [image: Solution Explorer]

I even navigated to the App_data folder in File explorer, turned on 'view hidden files' and still don't see anything. I think this folder is empty

[image: FileExplorer]

EDIT

[image: SlashError]

Comment: Can you add your web.config and Identity Model code, just trying to remember what goes where, there should also be some kind of entity context for the login in the project

Comment: @armand No problem. Post has been updated to include those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database is most likely in your App_Data folder, but not included in your project. Click on "Show all Files" at the top of the solution explorer to view it. 
In order to get this database in the same location as your Recipies database, you'll need to add another connection string and modify your IdentityModels.cs class (below) to use this new connection string (this will create the same database as it does currently, just in the location you indicate).

```
  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("UsersConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

If you want all the tables from the ApplicationDBContext to be included in your Recipies database (you weren't specific), then you need to make sure your RecipeContext inherits from IdentityDbContext and create a static method call Create:

```
 public class RecipeContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
    public static RecipeContext Create()
    {
        return new RecipeContext();
    }
}
```

and modify your ApplicationUserManager (IdentityConfig.cs) to use your RecipeContext in the Create method:

```
  var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<RecipeContext>()));
```

and modify the ConfigureAuth method in Startup.Auth.cs

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(RecipeContext.Create);
```

**Edit 2**
Make sure you include this line in your OnModelCreating override:

```
 base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

Comment: Matty. I updated my post. I really don't think this database is int he App_data folder. I will try your suggestion. But am i simply modifying where it says 'defaultConnection' to my database 'RecipeContext' ?

Comment: No. Are you trying to have 2 separate databases in your sql server instance or have one "Recipes" database that includes your user tables?

Comment: I just want 1 single database that contains all my tables.

Comment: See my edit. I believe it's all you need to do (you may need to drop your existing Recipe database if it already exists).

Comment: I appreciate your help Matty. Doing my best. So your first code example. Should I replace my entire RecipeContext.cs file with the code you have provided? (minus the using directives of course)

Comment: Yes. You'll also need to make the other changes I added.

Comment: Hi matty. I've made your changes. And successfully built the project. But now im getting a server error. I've updated my original post to show the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117130/discussion-between-matty-m-and-ontheinternet).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the connection string in your `web.config`, your database is in the [LocalDB](http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.io/projects/mvc/en/latest/getting-started/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql.html).

> LocalDB is a lightweight version of the SQL Server Express Database Engine that is targeted for program development. LocalDB starts on demand and runs in user mode, so there is no complex configuration. By default, LocalDB database creates “*.mdf” files in the C:/Users/ directory.